# Test data for tasks that communicate over network

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, scheduling, data-sets

I am working on a load balancer that schedules tasks that communicate over network. I want to test its performance, but I'm struggling to find test data for it. Currently I try to extract relevant data from google-cluster 2019 (https://github.com/google/cluster-data), microsoft azure (https://github.com/Azure/AzurePublicDataset) and alibaba (https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/594340). Maybe there is already such test data that I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the perfect site for this interesting question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can you suggest a site where I can ask?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps someone else will have a suggestion.

Comment: Even if I had test data (which I don't), how would you know whether it is representative of the type of data you are going to experience in your particular use scenario?  I don't think there are any shortcuts; to be useful, you'll probably have to gather data on the kinds of workloads that it will experience when it is used.